# If $X(t) = \int_0^t \sigma(s) dW(s)$, show that $X$ is normal.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Define $X(t) = \int_0^t \sigma(s) dW(s)$ where $W$ is a Wiener process aand $\sigma(s)$ some deterministic process. Informally this is the same as $dX(s) = \sigma(s) dW(s)$.

I wish to show that $X(t)$ is normally distributed with $0$ mean and variance $\int_0^t \sigma^2(s)ds$.

By letting $Z(t) = e^{u X(t)}$, we obtain from Ito's formula that $$dZ(t) = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(t) u^2 Z(t)dt + \sigma(t)uZ(t) dW(t). $$
In integral form, this is $$Z(t) = 1 + \int_0^t \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(s) u^2 Z(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) uZ(s) dW(s). $$
Then we take expectations and after that, we differentiate in order to get a solvable DE.

**First problem:** Can I just move an expectation inside the first integral above?

**Second problem:** Is the expectation of the second integral 0? I know this to be true if the integrand is an adapted process which satisfies a particular integrability condition, but I am unsure if all that is satisfied here?

**Third problem:** Assuming the answers to above are yes, yes, we then want to take the derivative on both sides. On the right, the constant disappears but the integral remains. How do I take its derivative? Informally, I would presume it equals $\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(t) u^2Z(t)$. Is this true?

**Fourth problem**: If the answer to above is yes, how do I solve the DE? I am unsure what to do with $\sigma$ when it depends on $t$.

Comment: You have stated that informally this is the process $dX(s) = \sigma(s)dWs$, of course this is no more informal then any other presentation of an SDE, I think maybe you have introduced some confusion with this new variable $Z$, but all the properties you want come from the Ito integral itself. For example you can find the variance by applying the Ito isometry result if you have seen this?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308120/finding-the-distribution-of-an-ito-integral-int-0t-sb-s-mathrmds?rq=1  - which is the special case when you function $\sigma(s) = s$, have a look at the accepted answer and see how you can adapt those results to the more general, but still deterministic, case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that we obtain $$Z(t) = 1 + \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\sigma(s)^2u^2 Z(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s)u Z(s) dW(s), $$ $$ \Longrightarrow E(Z(t)) \equiv g(t) = 1 + \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\sigma(s)^2 u^2 g(t) + \int_0^t \sigma(s)ug(t)dW(s),$$ $$\Longrightarrow g'(t) = \sigma(t)^2 \frac{1}{2}u^2 g(t) \Longrightarrow g(t) = e^{\int_0^t  \frac{u^2}{2}\sigma(s)^2 ds}$$

Therefore, $E( e^{u X(t)}) =  e^{\int_0^t  \frac{u^2}{2}\sigma(s)^2 ds}.$ Now recall that a normally distributed variable $N$ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ has $E( e^{u N(t)}) = e^{ \frac{1}{2}u^2 \sigma^2 }.$ By comparison, we see that $X(t)$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\int_0^t \sigma(s)^2 ds$.

We used in the above calculations integrability and that the Ito-integral disappears once we take expectations. See your problem formulation in order to determine whether these assumptions are satisfied. They depend on the properties of $\sigma(s)$.

Comment: If you are really arguing that this is the question the OP intended to ask then fair enough, I still believe he meant to ask the question in the heading and his second line... you argue that since the majority of his text was about the process $Z_t$ then this is the important feature, and I'm not sure that is the case, but there we go I'm sure the OP will clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are studying $Z_t$, it sounds redundant... by construction you integral is normal. You know exactly what is $Z_t$.

It is an Ito integral with a deterministic integrand on the Brownian side, therefore it is normal.
The Ito isometry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry can help you to get the variance.

First problem : yes, if you assume intregrability.
Second problem : it exists if $E(\int_0^t {(\sigma(s)uZ(s))}^2 ds) <\infty$

Third and four :I am not sure what you mean, but refer to the first lines I wrote

Comment: This is not an answer to the questions being asked. It should be a comment.

Comment: Read the question : show that X is normal , not clear ?  He is trying to prove that X is normal using  Ito's lemma on a more complicated function.

Comment: Yeah in defense of @Canardini he has addressed the meat of the problem - normality of the Ito integral, the problems in bold really stem from the unnecessary complexity introduced by the transformation to this new processes $Z_t$, which looks like is just an attempt to transform the given $X(t)$ to a process of the form $dZ(t) = fdt + gdW_t$, because this is how these things get presented, when really the object of interest is the Ito integral $\int_0^t \sigma(s) dW_s$.

Comment: @Nadiels: The meat of the problem is what OP spent 90 % of his question on, which is the introduction of Z and its stochastic differential. Canardini then proceeded to ignore all of that, and (poorly) gave a different answer, which clearly uses theory the OP has yet to study - if the OP knew of the knowledge presumed in Canardini's answer, the OP would not have asked this question in this shape to begin with.

Comment: @Jaood Ok I'm new to all this so I'm not going to get overly involved here and I don't know where the line is drawn as far as responders answering the question they believe was *intended* which I still maintain is the normality of the Ito integral and not the questions about adaptedness and measurability and so on of this $Z_t$ process. With that in mind I would agree that the answer was terse and not wonderfully set out - but he still points out that the normality follows from propertys of the Ito integral and surely the OP has begun the study of that theory?